# Explanation in REGEXP_REPLACE function output

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Following two query gives some output,

```
 Select REGEXP_REPLACE('Milind,Milind,Gopal,Gopal,Gopal,Milind'), '([^,]+) (,\1)+(,|$)', '\1\3') "OUTPUT"
FROM dual;

o/p Milind,Gopal,Milind


Select REGEXP_REPLACE('Milind,Milind,Gopal,Gopal,Gopal,Milind'), '([^,]+) (,\1+)(,|$)', '\1\3') "OUTPUT"
FROM dual;

o/p Milind,Gopal,Gopal,Milind
```

I do not understand the workflow. How it is giving output. 
Can anyone help me out and explain.

Comment: The first RegEx removes *one* following name which matches the previous name. #2 removes *all* following names. you can check RegExes on rexex101.com to see how they work: https://regex101.com/r/Xutku1/1

Comment: These patterns are regular NFA expressions. See https://regex101.com/r/USv2Et/1 and https://regex101.com/r/USv2Et/2 for explanation. The main thing here is a *repeated capturing group*, `(,\1)+`. You should avoid quantifying groups like this when you intend to quantify an atom inside the group.

Answer (score 1):

`[^,]` matches one character, that can be anything except a comma. For example: `M`.

`[^,]+` matches 1 or more times any character except a comma. For example: `Milind`

`([^,]+)` same, but capture the result, so it can be referenced later with `\1`.

`(,\1)+` matches a comma followed by the previous capture, one or more times, and capture the result as `\2`. If `\1` is `Milind`, it can match: `,Milind`, or `,Milind,Milind` or `,Milind,Milind,Milind`, etc.

`(,|$)` matches either a comma or the end of the line, and captures it as `\3`.

`\1\3` This is the replacement pattern: we are only keeping `\1` and `\3`, so everything matched in capture `\2` is effectively removed.

The second statement is showing a small difference that introduces a bug:

`(,\1+)` matches a comma followed by one or more occurences of the previous capture, as in: `,Milind`, or `,MilindMilind` or `,MilindMilindMilind`. As a result, it fails to remove several comma separated occurences.

Comment: Thanks Jerome. Helped a lot in seeing and understanding the workflow. You are awesome.